# Is there a simple way to format a decimal to a string in sql

Tags: sql-server, string, decimal

I need format a decimal number to a char(12) (right aligned) by following rules:

```
0 -> .00
0.12 -> .12
9.80 -> 9.80
-2.12 -> 2.12-
```

Is there any string format function in sql I could use? or I have to write my own function?

Comment: What database are you using?  Do you want a blank space after positive numbers?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008. If a number is positive, we will not show the sign.

Comment: I meant, do you want a space left empty when the number is positive, or just simple right-aligned?

Comment: That's not a list of rules; that's a guessing game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While formatting text in SQL is not ideal, I think the following gets you close. Using a `CASE` statement to move the sign, and `RIGHT()` to add padding, and `REPLACE()` to remove the leading zero from values under 1:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT('            '+CASE WHEN col1  < 0 
                                            THEN CAST(col1 *-1 AS VARCHAR(12))+'-'
                                         ELSE CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(12))   
                                    END,12),' 0.','  .')
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL is not designed to format numbers. You should handle the formatting in your application, whether it be a custom app, a reporting tool, etc.

Of course, you can use cast(), convert() and a whole bunch of character formatting to show whatever you want with SQL, but again, SQL is not really designed to do this very well, whereas applications are.

Answer (score 0):

```
LTRIM(STR(ABS(num),8,2)) + CASE SIGN(num) WHEN -1 THEN '-' ELSE '' END
```